# Observable Array doesn't reset in Knokcout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, computed-observable

I have an observable array as:

```
self.myArray = ko.observableArray([1234]);
```

I am trying to clear an observable array as two different ways:

```
self.myArray([]) // Step X
self.myArray.removeAll() // Step X
```

But the value isn't emptied, and then I have to perform:

```
self.myArray = ko.observableArray([]); // Step Y
```

Is step X's same as step Y?

Comment: Step X is not the same as step Y. In step X you are using the same observableArray you created before, whereas in step Y you are just assigning a new observableArray to your self.myArray. Meaning if you have bindings to myArray, and later you execure step Y, but you bindings will still be bound to previous observableArray. So you should not use step Y, step X is the correct one. Maybe the reason it's not being emptied is that you call self.myArray = ko.observableArray([1234]) more than one time?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your array is not empty after `removeAll()`?

The test would be `self.myArray().length === 0`:

```js
const test = ko.observableArray([1,2,3]);

console.log(test().length);

test.removeAll();

console.log(test().length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```